# Replace Content Only with Navbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile

I've been searching how to replace content with navbar, and I found this site : [Nested Content with Navbars using jQuery Mobile](http://matthewturland.com/2012/08/18/nested-content-with-navbars-using-jquery-mobile/), & completely can't understand how's the javascript works. yes, I'm a newbie in this field.

so, somehow he managed to create content like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HSlLW.gif) with this code :

```
<div data-role="page">
  <div data-role="header">
    <div data-role="navbar">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#one" class="ui-btn-active ui-btn-persist">One</a></li>
        <li><a href="#two">Two</a></li>
        <li><a href="#three">Three</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div data-role="content">
    <div id="one">One content</div>
    <div id="two">Two content</div>
    <div id="three">Three content</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and

```
(function($) {

// Before handling a page change...
$(document).bind("pagebeforechange", function(e, data)
{
    // If the new page is not being loaded by URL, bail
    if (typeof data.toPage !== "string")
    {
        return;
    }

    // If the new page has a corresponding navbar link, activate its content div
    var url = $.mobile.path.parseUrl(data.toPage);
    var $a = $("div[data-role='navbar'] a[href='" + url.hash + "']");
    if ($a.length)
    {
        // Suppress normal page change handling since we're handling it here for this case
        e.preventDefault();
    }
    // If the new page has a navbar, activate the content div for its active item
    else
    {
        $a = $(url.hash + " div[data-role='navbar']").find("a.ui-btn-active");

        // Allow normal page change handling to continue in this case so the new page finishes rendering
    }

    // Show the content div to be activated and hide other content divs for this page
    var $content = $($a.attr("href"));
    $content.siblings().hide();
    $content.show();
});

})(jQuery);
```

I was going to create 3 contents with my navbars, and here's my code :

```
<div data-role="navbar" data-iconpos="bottom">
      <ul>
       <li><a href="#one" id="home" data-transition="fade" data-theme="" data-icon="home" class="ui-btn-active">Home</a></li>
       <li><a href="#two" id="vmap" data-transition="fade" data-theme="" data-icon="star">V-Map</a></li>
       <li><a href="#three" id="login" data-transition="fade" data-theme="" data-icon="check">Login</a></li>
      </ul>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content" align="center" style="margin:2em 1em 2em 1em;">
     <div id="one">First Content</div>
     <div id="two">Second Content</div>
     <div id="three">Third Content</div>
    </div>
```

I don't have a previous page like the sample gave, can anyone help me with the javascript?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you **reference to jQuery, jQuery Mobile** libraries in your code.
I assume the problem with the previous button is, that you don't have a **page and header div wrapper**.

You have to use his exact markup, including the page and header div.

```
<div data-role="page">
  <div data-role="header">
  <div data-role="navbar">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#one" class="ui-btn-active ui-btn-persist">One</a></li>
      <li><a href="#two">Two</a></li>
      <li><a href="#three">Three</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div data-role="content">
    <div id="one">One content</div>
    <div id="two">Two content</div>
    <div id="three">Three content</div>
  </div>
</div>
```